# I need two elements to switch places via CSS

Tags: html, css

I need some help with some css-positioning:

Everything is setup how I want it for mobile, but when displayed on bigger screens, I want the id="centerpicture" and id="centertext" to switch places.

I have tried the "float: left/right;" as you can see, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Please advice. Thanks.

```css
  @media (max-width:800px) {
   .htmlcontent {
    width: 98.5%;
   }
  
   .htmlpicture > img {
    display: block;
   }
   
   #topcontent {
    padding-top: 15px;
   }
  
   .htmltext > h2, p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   }
   
   .htmltext > h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
   }
   
   .htmltext > p {
    padding-top: 2px;
   }
  
   .htmltext {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
   }
  }
  
  @media (min-width:801px) {
   .htmlcontent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
   }
   
   .htmlpicture > img {
    display: block;
   }
   
   .htmltext {
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
   }
   
   #centerpicture {
    float: right;
   }
   
   #centertext {
    float: left;
   }
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="htmlcontent" id="topcontent">
  <div class="htmlpicture">
   <img src="https://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/grupos/gsi/img/placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder" height="100%" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="htmltext">
   <h2>WHO ARE WE?</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit facilisis vel commodo, sem luctus tellus ac penatibus dictumst nostra dapibus tristique. Fames gravida scelerisque id lobortis magnis conubia mauris orci mi, morbi sociis phasellus sed ullamcorper litora sodales. Odio velit ante varius bibendum, faucibus blandit maecenas ligula torquent, ad netus sociosqu.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="htmlcontent">
  <div class="htmlpicture" id="centerpicture">
   <img src="https://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/grupos/gsi/img/placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder" height="100%" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="htmltext" id="centertext">
   <h2>WHAT SETS US APART?</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit facilisis vel commodo, sem luctus tellus ac penatibus dictumst nostra dapibus tristique. Fames gravida scelerisque id lobortis magnis conubia mauris orci mi, morbi sociis phasellus sed ullamcorper litora sodales. Odio velit ante varius bibendum, faucibus blandit maecenas ligula torquent, ad netus sociosqu.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="htmlcontent">
  <div class="htmlpicture">
   <img src="https://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/grupos/gsi/img/placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder" height="100%" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="htmltext">
   <h2>COMMITED TO QUALITY</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit facilisis vel commodo, sem luctus tellus ac penatibus dictumst nostra dapibus tristique. Fames gravida scelerisque id lobortis magnis conubia mauris orci mi, morbi sociis phasellus sed ullamcorper litora sodales. Odio velit ante varius bibendum, faucibus blandit maecenas ligula torquent, ad netus sociosqu.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: flexbox --> order property

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: i cannot elaborate within comment :) simply search about the `order` property used with flexbox to get some idea

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look. Thanks.

Comment: I did something much easier. I looked up "grid order", and found when I sat id=centertext to order: -1; it did what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;` and `order` property. here is example. You can change order in media query.

```css
        
  
#main {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}

#main div {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}

   

div#myRedDIV   {order: 3;background:coral;}
div#myBlueDIV  {order: 1;background:lightgreen;}
div#myGreenDIV {order: 4;background:pink;}
div#myPinkDIV  {order: 2;background:red;}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
         div#myRedDIV   {order: 1;}
         div#myBlueDIV  {order: 2;}
         div#myGreenDIV {order: 3;}
         div#myPinkDIV  {order: 4;}    
}
```

```html
 

      <div id="main">
  <div id="myRedDIV">1</div>
  <div  id="myBlueDIV">2</div>
  <div id="myGreenDIV">3</div>
  <div  id="myPinkDIV">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is an option, but you are already using `display: grid` on the container. So you only need to add:

```
#centertext {
    order: -1;
}
```

I suggest you avoid using `#ids` for specifying CSS, rely only on `.class` selectors. Reasons for this can be found on the net, but for example BEM [uses only class selectors](http://getbem.com/naming/).

```css
@media (max-width:800px) {
   .htmlcontent {
    width: 98.5%;
   }
  
   .htmlpicture > img {
    display: block;
   }
   
   #topcontent {
    padding-top: 15px;
   }
  
   .htmltext > h2, p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   }
   
   .htmltext > h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
   }
   
   .htmltext > p {
    padding-top: 2px;
   }
  
   .htmltext {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
   }
  }
  
  @media (min-width:801px) {
   .htmlcontent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
   }
   
   .htmlpicture > img {
    display: block;
   }
   
   .htmltext {
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
   }
   
   #centertext {
    order: -1;
   }
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="htmlcontent" id="topcontent">
  <div class="htmlpicture">
   <img src="https://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/grupos/gsi/img/placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder" height="100%" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="htmltext">
   <h2>WHO ARE WE?</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit facilisis vel commodo, sem luctus tellus ac penatibus dictumst nostra dapibus tristique. Fames gravida scelerisque id lobortis magnis conubia mauris orci mi, morbi sociis phasellus sed ullamcorper litora sodales. Odio velit ante varius bibendum, faucibus blandit maecenas ligula torquent, ad netus sociosqu.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="htmlcontent">
  <div class="htmlpicture" id="centerpicture">
   <img src="https://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/grupos/gsi/img/placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder" height="100%" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="htmltext" id="centertext">
   <h2>WHAT SETS US APART?</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit facilisis vel commodo, sem luctus tellus ac penatibus dictumst nostra dapibus tristique. Fames gravida scelerisque id lobortis magnis conubia mauris orci mi, morbi sociis phasellus sed ullamcorper litora sodales. Odio velit ante varius bibendum, faucibus blandit maecenas ligula torquent, ad netus sociosqu.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="htmlcontent">
  <div class="htmlpicture">
   <img src="https://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/grupos/gsi/img/placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder" height="100%" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="htmltext">
   <h2>COMMITED TO QUALITY</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit facilisis vel commodo, sem luctus tellus ac penatibus dictumst nostra dapibus tristique. Fames gravida scelerisque id lobortis magnis conubia mauris orci mi, morbi sociis phasellus sed ullamcorper litora sodales. Odio velit ante varius bibendum, faucibus blandit maecenas ligula torquent, ad netus sociosqu.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used flex-direction: row-reversed on the parent div to achieve this. I had to use flex-basis: 50% on the child divs to make sure they each take 50% of the page.

```
@media (min-width:801px) {

            .htmlpicture > img {
                display: block;
            }

            .htmltext {
                padding: 12px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .desktop-reversed {
                display:flex;
                flex-direction: row-reverse;
            }
            .desktop-reversed div {
                flex-basis:50%;
            }
        }



<div class="htmlcontent desktop-reversed">
        <div class="htmlpicture" id="centerpicture">
            <img src="https://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/grupos/gsi/img/placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder" height="100%" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="htmltext" id="centertext">
            <h2>
                WHAT SETS US APART?
            </h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit facilisis vel commodo, sem luctus tellus ac penatibus dictumst nostra dapibus tristique. Fames gravida scelerisque id lobortis magnis conubia mauris orci mi, morbi sociis phasellus sed ullamcorper litora sodales. Odio velit ante varius bibendum, faucibus blandit maecenas ligula torquent, ad netus sociosqu.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```